# Git clone a repo containing a submodule with modifications

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo with a submodule where the submodule has modifications/commits that have *not* been pushed to the remote from which it originated.

I would like to clone this parent repo with the submodule and keep the modifications while maintaining the git history from which I'm attempting to clone (this includes the modifications in the submodule).

I have tried
`git clone --recurse-submodules https://some.domain.ca/path/to/repo.git`
but this leads to the following error

```
fatal: git upload-pack: not our ref 063e202da5c92a701892a121db16e5c66d661725
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 063e202da5c92a701892a121db16e5c66d661725
Fetched in submodule path 'submodule-name', but it did not contain 063e202da5c92a701892a121db16e5c66d661725. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

I believe this error occurs because the submodule in the repo has a history that doesn't match that of the remote from which it originated.

How do I clone the repo with the submodule and its modifications that are not represented in the submodule reference?

Comment: A submodule is just a reference to a commit in another repository. That commit needs to be available when cloning the submodule.

Comment: The submodule directory on your disk is already a clone : you can cd into it, then `git status`, `git commit`, `git remote add ...`, `git pull/push` will happen within that submodule (not within its parent repository). What do you want to do with your submodule ?

Comment: Otherwise : `git clone` somewhere else, `git checkout` to the correct branch or commit, then `cp` the files from subrepo to new clone

Answer (score 0):

The comment by larsks was instructive in thinking about how to reference the desired commits in the submodule.

Here's the steps I took to duplicate the initial repo with the modified submodule:

1. Clone the repo; `git clone https://some.domain.ca/path/to/repo.git`
2. Modify the url in `.gitmodules` to reference the submodule in the source repo
3. Run `git submodule update --init --recursive`
4. Restore `.gitmodules`

This does mean that any further modifications within the submodule will be unknown to other clones, but these steps can be repeated for an update.